# Relative paths in JBoss Application Server 7

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I would like to specify file paths using the JBoss provided substitutions, e.g. ${jboss.server.log.dir}.

I see that there are entries in standalone.xml such as

```
<file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
```

but I don't think I can use that everywhere I need a relative path.  For example, I want to point to a keystore in .../standalone/ssl so I would like to just put

```
<ssl certificate-key-file="${jboss.server.base.dir}/ssl/cert"/>
```

as I would in JBoss 6 and earlier but when JBoss starts it cannot find the file *${jboss.server.base.dir}/ssl/cert* and I have to fill in the absolute path to the file.

Is there something that I need to turn on in standalone.xml to make this work or is this no longer possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of JBoss AS 7.1.0.Final, some SSL configuration can now be done using system property expressions. Using the following, should now work:

```
<ssl certificate-key-file="${jboss.server.base.dir}/ssl/cert"/>
```

- JBoss AS 7 ticket AS7-3506 (https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-3506)

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on this for awhile but finally came back to it.
According to the xsd the  element does not support a "relative-to" attribute nor does property substitution work.  The best I can come up with, which is good enough, is to reference the file relative to the bin directory.  Now that I figured it out it makes sense and I wish I'd thought of trying that earlier.

On a side note, until JBoss AS 7.1 comes out the "ca-certificate-file" attribute for  is ignored. You must set

```
    <system-properties>
          <property name="javax.net.ssl.trustStore" value="<path to truststore>"/>
</system-properties>
```

or add the property to the command that launches JBoss.